# Error on completion of Data Extract and File Transfer

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, data-extract

I'm currently experiencing an error on the Automation Studio with related to the Data Extract - One of the activity get failed by "Error has occurred" and File Transfer - one of the activity flagged "File transfer failed because the source file is locked."

A brief explanation of why this error occurs would help me to patch it up and prevent it to occur moving forward.  Does anyone experience the same issues as I had?

Please do share your knowledge on this =]

Answer (score 2):

The file is likely [in use by another process](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_automation_studio_errors.htm&type=5). You can:

- Retry the activity or the automation that it's a part of if this error does not typically occur.
- If this error continues, ensure that the file is not being used by another process.

It is also very likely that the previously transferred file was interrupted in the middle of being processed and put in a locked state and the file can't be replaced.

**Create new data extract and file transfer activities** or wait 2 days for the process to timeout and clear.